# MySQL Query Explanation: Index choosing when the query has "WHERE" as well as "ORDER BY"

Tags: mysql

There is something I cannot understand when I try to optimize my query using index.

The table looks like this:

```
create table order_table (
  id int not null primary key,
  customer_id varchar(50) not null,
  sale int not null,
  key customer_sale_idx (customer_id, sale)
);
```

when I run `explain select * from order_table where customer_id=2 order by sale limit 1;`

It shows

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: order_table
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: customer_sale_idx
          key: customer_sale_idx
      key_len: 206
          ref: NULL
         rows: 5
     filtered: 20.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using filesort
```

And then I add another index `alter table order_table add key sale_customer_idx (sale, customer_id);`

now the `explain select * from order_table where customer_id=2 order by sale limit 1;` query shows

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: order_table
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: customer_sale_idx
          key: sale_customer_idx
      key_len: 206
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 20.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

Q1: I suppose mysql should check the `customer_id` first, get those records that match the `where`, then do the `sort` by `sale`. It uses the `customer_sale_idx` index as I expected, but I don't konw why it use `Using filesort` rather than utilize the cover index
`(customer_id, sale)` to do the sort.

Q2: MySQL uses the new index `sale_customer_idx (sale, customer_id)` after I added it. But I don't understand how this index helps to get rid of the `Using filesort`.

Q3: The latter `explain` says there is only one `possible_keys` which is `customer_sale_idx`, but then it use `sale_customer_idx`. How?

BTW,I know it's strange that `customer_id` is `varchar`. But let's just focus on explaining this phenomenon.

Comment: Good question +1 ... I don't have an explanation for the filesort step in the first case.  MySQL should be able to rely on the `sale` part of the index to find the lowest sale.

Comment: Interesting to [note](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c372e1555b2a0fcb7f133866cc53c502) how the query plan changes when customer_id is a string rather than a number

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It turns out that I didn't notice the type conversion(`customer_id` is `varchar` while `2` is `int`). Please check **Solarflare's Answer** for more detail.

Comment: @Sean The big question now is that if you fix the type casting problem, does the filesort in the first index go away?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. If I use `customer_id='2'` rather than `customer_id=2`, the `Using filesort` disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has to cast the first column of your index `(customer_id, sale)` to an integer. So it cannot use the second column to sort.

```
... where customer_id=2 ...
```

will be true for `customer_id`s with the varchar values `'2'`, `'02'`, `'002'`, `'2 and a half men'` and many more. It cannot jump to `'2'`, read the first row and assume that it is one with the lowest `sale`-value, as there can also be `'02'` with a lower `sale`-value. Only this would allow MySQL to not sort.

Instead it has to go through the whole table, cast every row, check if it `= 2` after casting, take the ones that are, and sort whatever is left. That's why you have the filesort there. MySQL doesn't know you have nothing else there that would cast to 2.

In fact, it could do the same with the primary key. Since your index is covering, they are equivalent.

You can verify this if you do the comparison with a varchar, which doesn't require casting, thus the index entries it finds are correctly ordered by the second column `sale`:

```
... where customer_id='2' ...
```

Now it can do exactly as it was expected: jump to `'2'`, take the first row, stop. No sort required. MySQL knows: this is the row with the lowest value for `sale`.

Your index `(sale, customer_id)` works the following way: it reads all values, ordered by sale, until it reaches one that is (autocasted) equal to `2`. MySQL can be sure now that this is the one you wanted (as you checked all lower values of `sale` already, none of them fit your condition on `customer_id`. Thus, no ordering is required.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I just check the result using `customer_id="2"`. And the explanation about index `(sale, customer_id)` is pretty convincing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are very few rows in that table. With very small tables, table scans and sorting operations can be cheaper than index scans. Once you have a few thousand rows in it, the execution plan will be more predictable.